# scope passed to service is not updating the view

Tags: angularjs

This is an app that I took over from another developer.  I have a controller that calls a function inside a service and it passes in the $scope of the controller as a parameter.  THis exact same thing is done with another function in the service.

THe problem is that only one of these services seem to update the view.

Here is my code (very condensed to keep it short, or a short as possible)

```
var KrisisEventsApp = angular.module('KrisisEventsApp', []);

KrisisEventsApp.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });

//Controller for registration
KrisisEventsApp.controller('RegistrationCtrl',

    ['$scope', 'RegistrationService', '$timeout',

        function ($scope, RegistrationService, $timeout) {

            $scope.SaveRegistrantData =
            function () {

                //save user input
                RegistrationService.SaveRegistrationForm($scope);

            };

            $scope.Products_Continue =
            function () {

                RegistrationService.ListItemsForCart($scope);
            };

        }

    ]

);
```

```
KrisisEventsApp.service('RegistrationService',

    ['$http', function ($http) {

        var thisService = this;

        //injects custom properties into registration form
        thisService.SaveRegistrationForm = function ($scope) {

            this.count = 0;
            this._scope = $scope;

            // if no product are found, go straight to payment page
            this.count = Object.keys($scope.products).length;
            // console.log(this.count);

            $http({

                method: "POST",
                url: v_ModulePath + "/API/Registrants_WebAPI/RegisterUser",
                dataType: 'text/plain',
                data: data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                    'ModuleId': v_servicesFramework.getModuleId(),
                    'TabId': v_servicesFramework.getTabId(),
                    'RequestVerificationToken': v_servicesFramework.getAntiForgeryValue()
                }
            })
              .then(function (response) {

                  data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data))

                  this.config2 = {
                      method: "GET",
                      url: v_ModulePath + "/API/Registrants_WebAPI/ListItemsForCart?idregistrant=" + $("#hid_registrant_id").val() + "&idevent=" + v_EventID,
                      dataType: 'text/plain',
                      data: '',
                      headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                          'ModuleId': v_servicesFramework.getModuleId(),
                          'TabId': v_servicesFramework.getTabId(),
                          'RequestVerificationToken': v_servicesFramework.getAntiForgeryValue()
                      }
                  }

                  return $http.get(v_ModulePath + "/API/Registrants_WebAPI/ListItemsForCart?idregistrant=" + $("#hid_registrant_id").val() + "&idevent=" + v_EventID, this.config2);
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                  data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
                  $scope.Cart = data;
              });
        }


        //list cart items
        thisService.ListItemsForCart = function ($scope) {

            $http(

               {
                   method: "GET",
                   url: v_ModulePath + "/API/Registrants_WebAPI/ListItemsForCart?idregistrant=" + $("#hid_registrant_id").val() + "&idevent=" + v_EventID,
                   dataType: 'text/plain',
                   data: '',
                   headers: {
                       'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                       'ModuleId': v_servicesFramework.getModuleId(),
                       'TabId': v_servicesFramework.getTabId(),
                       'RequestVerificationToken': v_servicesFramework.getAntiForgeryValue()
                   }
               }).success(function (data) {

                   data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data));
                   $scope.Cart = data;

               }).error(function (data) {

               });
        }

    }

    ]

);
```

Here is the view (portion):

```
...
<a ng-click="SaveRegistrantData()" class="small button success" id="but_InputForm_MoveNext">Continue</a>

...
<a ng-click="Products_Continue()" class="small button success">Continue</a>

...
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="CartItem in Cart.Cart_Items_List">
        <td>{{ CartItem.Item_Description }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ CartItem.Item_Fee }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total to Pay</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{ Cart.CartTotal }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

You can see that the **SaveRegistrationForm** and **ListItemsForCart** functions are called from the controller, which are in turn initiated by button clicks from the view.

NOTE:

the following lines are the important ones in each function:

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
$scope.Cart = data;
```

### PROBLEM:

Only the **ListItemsForCart** updates the view, when I run the **SaveRegistrationForm** function the view does not update.

I have used fiddler to examine the web api calls and both functions successfully return the same data.

I have also used the chrome console to confirm that the $scope.Cart object does in fact get assigned the right data.

### QUESTION:

Can someone help me figure out why my view is not updating?

Comment: Are SaveRegistrantData and Products_Continue functions called in the same way? It might be the case one of them (the one which does not update the scope in the end) might be called in a way which does not trigger the digest cycle. Try to put $scope.$applyAsync() after $scope.Cart = data;. If that solves the problem, make sure you call the function "within" Angular.

Comment: @VladimirZdenek thanks, I added the applyAsync but this did not fix the issue.  The functions are called from button clicks, from different buttons, but what I posted is the only place they are called in my code.

Comment: i added the links that call each function

Comment: Put a `.catch` method at the end of the chain and console.log the error response. My guess is that the first `.then` function is throwing a "can't assign property of `undefined`" error.

Comment: You basic design is flawed, `$scope` should not be passed to service, instead return promise from service and use them in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I inherited this app from another developer.  **They defined the controller with the same name twice in the html view**.  arrrrg.  So the second set of data that was not updating was in the second instance of the controller.

Once I moved a single controller instance to wrap the whole view the problems all went away.

Thanks to all who helped.  You would not have been able to tell this from the abbreviated view code I posted.  (I also have many other things to update, like .success to then catch and like Satpal said: just returning promises from my services etc...)